# Check pointer in struct is NULL

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have some problem in checking if pointer in my structure is null, it's my code :

```
zone* z = malloc(sizeof(zone));
z->cases = malloc(sizeof(Case)*300);

for(i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    Case* c = z->cases[i];

    if(c->fourmilier) // HERE IS RAISE SEGMENTATION FAULT
    {
        if(read( &nbTypeFourmib, sizeof( unsigned char))==-1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

My struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short foodSpawnfreq;
    unsigned short foodUnit;
    unsigned char sourceFood;
    Case** cases;
    TypeFourmi** TypeFourmi;
    TypeFourmi** TypeBibibte;
} zone;

typedef struct{
    fourmiliere* fourmilier;
    bibite* bibit;
    fourmis* fourmi;
    char obstacle;
} Case;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You struct specified the type of `case` to be `Case**`. However, you are assigning a `Case*` to it.

What you need to do is change:

```
z->cases = malloc(sizeof(Case)*300);
```

To...

```
z->cases = malloc(sizeof(Case*)*300);
```

And inside your loop...

```
z->cases[i] = malloc(sizeof(Case));

// initialise data

Case* c = z->cases[i];
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to change type to `Case**` to `Case*`, and use `Case* c = &z->cases[i];` instead.

Comment: @user694733 yes, but it's hard to tell what the end goal of this code is so I just went with the direct route

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if((NULL != c) && c->fourmilier)
```

I think that you actually need something like

```
z->cases = new Case[300];
```

instead of

```
z->cases = malloc(sizeof(Case)*300);
```

Comment: The original question looks like C (hence why I tagged it as such), and if this is the case there is no `new` keyword :)

Comment: I have not paid attention to tags :(